# How many partitions of number 25 exist such that the ferrers diagram matches the transposed ferrers diagram?

Tags: combinatorics

I need help solving this question. I though about the symmetry about the y=-x line. I had an idea of running through all possible number of points on this line (only even number would work, since the line divides the diagram into two equal parts and the number of total points is 25), but I don't know how to count the possible arrangements of points on one side. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You might find it easier to count the partitions of $25$ into distinct odd parts; the two counts [are the same](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Conjugate_and_self-conjugate_partitions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of self-conjugate partitions of $n$ is the same as the number of distinct odd partitions of $n$. (This is easy to see by splitting a self-conjugate diagram into "ells" from the corner.) $25$ is an odd number, so may only be split into $1,3,5$ distinct odd parts – and the only partitions with $1$ and $5$ such parts are $25$ and $1+3+5+7+9$ respectively. The number of partitions with $3$ distinct odd parts is nine:
$$21+3+1$$
$$19+5+1$$
$$17+7+1,17+5+3$$
$$15+9+1,15+7+3$$
$$13+11+1,13+9+3,13+7+5$$
So there are $11$ admissible partitions of $25$.

Comment: That makes perfect sense, thank you!!